# How can a foxhole radio tune in on a frequency without a capacitor?

Tags: radio, amplitude-modulation, crystal-set

A primitive foxhole radio only consists of an antenna, coil, diode and headphones. There doesn't seem to be an LC-resonator, so how does this radio tune in on a carrier frequency?

[image: foxhole radio]

Comment: It probably doesn't do so very well.  All it really needed to do was to pick up the single radio station in range of the foxhole.  Tuning wasn't really the strong point of such a radio.

Comment: No tuning.  Set up for (or close to) one frequency.  Trial and error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The coil will have a certain amount of self-capacitance, which will be enough for resonance. The resonant frequency will be in the broadcast band if it has enough turns.

Comment: Thanks! Am I correct in assuming that the resonant frequency you describe is the same as the coil's self-resonant frequency described [here](http://www.analogictips.com/when-inductors-self-resonate/)?

Comment: Yes, it would be.